# spring state machine throws NullPointerException when you throw exception from your action

Tags: java, spring, state-machine, spring-statemachine

When I throw an exception from the custom action defined in the StateMachineConfigurerAdapter, any subsequent call to state machine throws NPE as it gets null currentState .

My call to state machine is:

```
PersistStateMachineHandler handler;    
handler.handleEventWithState(
                        MessageBuilder
                                .withPayload(event)
                                .setHeader("key", data)
                                .build()
                        ,
                        previousState
                )
```

The stacktrace is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.statemachine.support.AbstractStateMachine.acceptEvent(AbstractStateMachine.java:591)
    at org.springframework.statemachine.support.AbstractStateMachine.sendEvent(AbstractStateMachine.java:202)
    at org.springframework.statemachine.recipes.persist.PersistStateMachineHandler.handleEventWithState(PersistStateMachineHandler.java:81)
```

And the reason is that this.currentState.getIds() is throwing NPE as currentState is coming null.

It seems there is some code issue in AbstractStateMachine

```
protected synchronized boolean acceptEvent(Message<E> message)
```

the last line is not handling currentState != null condition, as all previous one is handling it. You can skip this exception by explicitily passing the currentState, which is not required in general. But even if after giving the currentState, it is not calling the onPersist() method of the persistStateChangeListener

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to use the context supplied by `void execute(StateContext<S, E> context);` in the `org.springframework.statemachine.action.Action<S, E>` interface.

Once you have the context you can access the StateMachine via `StateMachine<S, E> getStateMachine();`

in the `StateMachine` set the exception in `void setStateMachineError(Exception exception);`

e.g.

`context.getStateMachine().setStateMachineError(new IllegalArgumentException("Ooops");`